# Create an email signature for Outlook

Tags: html, outlook, responsive, signature, display

I made an HTML signature but I can't manage to display it correctly on Outlook. Do you know why ?

Here's the signature : https://stefandigital.com/gettindigit/s/

Thank you guys for your help !

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook does not work with background images the way you are trying to impliment them. Read this article for more information:

https://litmus.com/community/learning/25-understanding-background-images-in-email

In addition, you're using css that Outlook does not understand. Check out this page for which css it does support:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Furthermore, you're using div. Outlook has issues with div. My suggestion is to use table instead, but that's another issue.

For more information about the issue with div, visit this page:

[Div styles not working in Outlook Emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765493/div-styles-not-working-in-outlook-emails)