# Outlook 2013 HTML display issue

Tags: php, html, email, outlook

i have this little but annoying issue displaying text content in the body of the mail. From a form page i send a mail HTML5 formatted.
This is what i sent via mail() php function:

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <style type='text/css'>
     body{
       font-family:'Lucida Grande', Arial;
       color:#333;
       font-size:15px;
     }
    .div1{ display:inline; }
    .row {margin-bottom:5px}
    .background {background-color:#ffe508; padding:5px; font-size:18px}
</style>
 </head>
  <body>
   <div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="div1"><strong>Company:</strong></div><div class="div1">&nbsp;  
   $company</div></div>
   </div>
    </body>
     </html>
```

This is what i display on OUTLOOK 2013:

**Company**:

company_name

It's wrong because i need to display this field on one line as i display fine on WLM

**Company**:
company_name

i also tried to use table instead of html5 but nothing changes.
Any idea? Thanks

Comment: unfortunately Outlook (and some other email clients, to be fair) is notoriously non-standards-compliant with it comes to HTML display. Trial and error is going to be your best approach, I suspect. Maybe try spans instead of divs, and/or inline styles.

Comment: I tried with simples float:left and display: inline-block; but seems there's no way to align horizontally 2 divs. This works only with live mail.

Comment: Did you float _both_ of them? What about spans, as I suggested? They are inline by default anyway.

Comment: Thanks ADyson for helping. I tried with spans but no changes. Outlook is really crap

Comment: Any reason you can't just get rid of the divs? What are they for? The line could just be `<strong>Company:</strong>&nbsp;$company`?

Comment: LOL! No, i don't have problems to get rid of the divs. Sometimes i waste my time to find solutions where i should simplify everything...Thanks, in this way works

Comment: No worries, I added it as the answer for you to accept - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the divs, then simply remove them. They don't appear to be doing anything. The line could just be:

```
<strong>Company:</strong>&nbsp;$company
```

This means there's nothing which could interfere with this part of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

CSS elements such as float, width and position of `<div>` doe not work in Outlook.

- [Div styles not working in Outlook Emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765493/div-styles-not-working-in-outlook-emails)

@ADyson is correct. You don't even need them in your example.

In addition, keep in mind that `margin` does not work. `Margin`  (capital M) does work. I understand that is not the correct use of Margin, but that's the way Outlook uses it. It's important to remember that email development is not Web development.

- https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/outlookcom-margins/

Good luck.