# display:inline-block not working outlook/gmail

Tags: html, css, outlook, gmail, responsive

I'm developing email templates and I need to use `display:inline-block` but it's not working on gmail and outlook.
I just need to align an image with a text and I can't use a table .

Any suggestions to make the `display:inline-block` work or any other solution that works on outlook and gmail?

this my code:

```html
<div>


  <span style="display:inline-block;">this is not<br/> working:</span>
  <a href="" target="_blank"><img style="vertical-align:middle;" alt="" border="0" src="img.jpg"></a>


</div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's only partial support in Outlook for `display:inline-block;`. Gmail should work fine.

> Outlook 2000–03
>   Partial. Supports block, inline, list-item, and none.
>
> Outlook 2007–16
>   Partial. Sometimes supports none.
>
> Outlook Express
>   Partial. Supports block, inline, list-item, and none.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

**Outlook doesn't support `<div>`**

Outlook doesn't really support `<div>` Classes and styles You can use them, but styles do not always get applied. I would suggest a table for reliability.

- [Div styles not working in Outlook Emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765493/div-styles-not-working-in-outlook-emails)

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use float:left in the style of "a" and "span"

```
<span style="float:left;">this is not<br/> working:</span>
    <a style="float:left;" href="" target="_blank"><img  alt="" border="0" src="yourImage.jpg"></a>
```

it works in my code

If it doesn't work on outlook it's because when it comes to rendering HTML, most email clients are primitive and will break a lot of well formed HTML elements.

I would recommend some online resources such as:

How To Code HTML Emails: [MailChimp](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/ways-to-build/about-html-email)

This SO discussion may be helpful:

[What guidelines for HTML email design are there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127498/what-guidelines-for-html-email-design-are-there)

Comment: not working just tried the image is going under the text

Comment: it's actually working but not on outlook i have height between "this is not" and working it's because of the span ...

Comment: i hope that the links in my answer will help you

Comment: Outlook doesn't support floats.